# For odd $n$, if $x^2 = a \pmod{n}$ has a solution then at least one solution has a specific representation.

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, quadratic-residues

Update:

̶F̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶d̶d̶ ̶$n$,̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶ $x^2 = a \pmod{n}$ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶i̶c̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶r̶e̶s̶e̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶

See the counterexample provided by lonza leggiera.

Also, see my [conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3901694/432081) (stated on November 10, 2020 and still open on November 14),

$\quad$ A new method for finding a solution to $x^2 = a \pmod p$?

arising from this initial work.

---

Here is the proposed representation,

For odd $n$, if $x^2 = a \pmod{n}$ has a solution then there is at least one solution $b$ such that there exists a $k \ge 0$ such that

$\tag 1 \text{The residue, } \Large 0 \lt r \lt n, \normalsize \text{ of } \, \Large 4^k  a \, \normalsize \text{ is a square}, \Large r = t^2$

$\tag 2 \LARGE b \equiv 2^{-k}  t \pmod{n}$

> Is the above proposed representation valid?

**My work**

What got me going on this can be found in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3898705/432081) to

$\quad$ *How to solve $x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod {13}$?*

I then looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1478848/432081)

$\quad$ How to solve $x^2\equiv 4\pmod{143}$?

and found that the representation works for all solutions.

Example 1:

We have $141^2 = 4 \pmod{143}$. Also,

$\quad 4^{38} \cdot 4 \equiv 25 \pmod{143}$

and

$\quad 141 \equiv 2^{-38} \cdot 5 \pmod{143}$

Example 2:

There are two solutions, $3$ and $4$ for $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$; the representation works for $4$ but not for $3$.

Example 3:

The representation, if sound, could be used to show that $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ has no solutions.

Our 'lookup table of squares', $S$, is defined by

$\quad S = \{1,4\}$

$\; 4^0 \cdot 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{7} \text{ and } 3 \notin S$
$\; 4^1 \cdot 3 \equiv 5 \pmod{7} \text{ and } 5 \notin S$
$\; 4^2 \cdot 3 \equiv 6 \pmod{7} \text{ and } 6 \notin S$
$\; 4^3 \cdot 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{7} \text{ and } 3 \notin S \text{ and the cycle repeats} $

and we could argue that $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ has no solutions.

Example 4:

Find (if it exists) a solution to $x^2 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$.

Our 'lookup table of squares', $S$, is defined by

$\quad S = \{1,4\}$

$\; 4^0 \cdot 7 \equiv 7 \pmod{9} \text{ and } 7 \notin S$
$\; 4^1 \cdot 7 \equiv 1 \pmod{9} \text{ and } 1 \in S$

There is a solution, $\large x \equiv 2^{-1} \times 1 \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$.

Example 5 (motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2172354/432081) question on quadratic reciprocity):

Find (if it exists) a solution to $x^2 \equiv 3\pmod {10007}$.

Our 'lookup table of squares', $S$, is defined by

```
1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
```

Calculating,

$\; 4^0 \cdot 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 3 \notin S$
$\; 4^1 \cdot 3 \equiv 12 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 12 \notin S$
$\; 4^2 \cdot 3 \equiv 48 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 48 \notin S$
$\; 4^3 \cdot 3 \equiv 192 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 192 \notin S$
$\; 4^4 \cdot 3 \equiv 768 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 768 \notin S$
$\; 4^5 \cdot 3 \equiv 3072 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 3072 \notin S$
$\; 4^6 \cdot 3 \equiv 2281 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 2281 \notin S$
$\; 4^7 \cdot 3 \equiv 9124 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 9124 \notin S$
$\; 4^8 \cdot 3 \equiv 6475 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 6475 \notin S$
$\dots\quad$(and writing several lines of python code)
$\; 4^{482} \cdot 3 \equiv 4664 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 4664 \notin S$
$\; 4^{483} \cdot 3 \equiv 8649 \pmod{10007} \text{ and } 8649 \in S$

and $8649 = 93 \times 93$.

There is a solution, $\large x \equiv 2^{-483} \times 93 \equiv 1477 \pmod{10007}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation is not always possible. If $\ n=63\ $ and $\ a=58\ $, then the equation $\ x^2=a\pmod{n}\ $ has the solutions $\ x=11\ $ and $\ x=52\ $.  If $\ r\ $ is a residue of $\ 4^ka\pmod{n}\ $, then its only possible values are $\ 58\,(k\equiv0\pmod{3})\ $, $\ 43\, (k\equiv1\pmod{3})\ $, and $\ 46\,(k\equiv2\pmod{3})\ $, none of which is a square.

Comment: Did you write a computer program to get the example?

Comment: No, although I did use an iPad app ([MathStudio](http://mathstud.io/apps/)) to help with the calculations.  I initially thought that a counterexample might be easy to find if $\ 2\ $ had small multiplicative order mod $n$.  I spent some time trying $n=31$ (and I did write some *MathStudio* scripts, in this case, to help with the search).  I eventually realised that it wasn't the order of $2$, but the order of $4$, which really mattered. After switching to $\ n=63\ $, the third square I tried (after $9^2$ and $10^2$) gave me the counterexample.

Comment: I noticed that $58 \cdot 25 \equiv 1  \pmod{63}$ but putting this on the back burner...